# Is there a way to allow administrators to change or reset user passwords?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, fba

We have a custom `MembershipProvider` implementation using **form-based authentication** (FBA) under Sharepoint 2007.

I've searched high and low on Google, but only found:

- Active directory and FBA implementations to allow users to change *their own* password
- Active directory instructions (including video!) for administrators to change other users' passwords

Have we missed an option to enable the latter under FBA? Should this work by default and is the `MembershipProvider` misbehaving?

The procedure to do this as under active directory would be ideal, but the "Change Password" link does not appear in the Edit User screen. We verified that the logged-in user is a site collection administrator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add appropriate option by yourself.

You can see example implementation in the [CKS FBA](http://cks.codeplex.com/releases/view/17901) project at CodePlex:

1. page [**UserEdit.aspx**](http://cks.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53654#358328) contains button `BtnReset`,
2. when it is clicked, method `OnResetPassword` from file [**UserEdit.cs**](http://cks.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/53654#358345) is called.

Comment: The page in question is `_layouts/userdisp.aspx`. We decided going down this route was too complicated, but I think this would work so I'm going to mark this answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: The Reset Password button is only displayed when the RequiresQuestionAndAnswer is false, and the EnablePasswordReset is true.  This is because if the security question and answer are turned on the admin will not know the answer to the question so they won't be able to reset the password anyways.

Answer (score -1):

Your forms based authentication was probably built in house (you mention that it is custom).  The developers would need to include a way for you to do this.  Short of that, find the table which stores the usernames and passwords and just change the password.  If it is encrypted you can probably just copy the password from an account which you know the password to, but this doesn't always work depending on how the password is salted.

Comment: The MembershipProvider was built in-house, but the UI is standard. There's no need to go hacking in the database. If the provider isn't fully implemented, then I can deal with that. I'm looking for a common solution (it looks as though there may not be one) before writing a custom solution.